# How can I add terms of service and privacy policy to a simple showcase website?

Tags: cookies, privacy-policy

I am a newbie developer, How can I add terms of service and privacy policy ?
If I plan to build for my first clients a simple showcase website that does not store any data,do I need to add them anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

Privacy Policies are required if you collect data from users directly or indirectly (ie. third-parties such as Google Analytics).

You can add the page just like any other normal website pages (ie. Contact).

Comment: Thanks,do you know some good terms of use / privacy policy generator?